# Azure Pipelines | App Center test | error when including category

Tags: xamarin.android, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center, xamarin.uitest

I'm running a job (series of tasks including nuget restore, build & signing application) on Azure DevOps to build android application and Test (Xamarin.UITest) application through Appcenter.

Test runs fine, if I don't specify any arguments on "Additional options for run" on "Test with Visual Studio App Center" task. When I do that (--include-category LandingPage) task throws error saying:

```
Error: Command 'test run manifest --manifest-path d:\a\12\a\AppCenterTest\manifest.json --app-path d:/a/12/b/Release/PUBLISH_PACKAGE_NAME_PHONE_ANDROID.PUBLISH_PACKAGE_NAME_PHONE_ANDROID.apk --app SampleApp/Android --devices 12345abcd --test-series DevOps --locale en_US --include-category LandingPage --quiet --token ***' failed with exception "Unknown argument --include-category"
```

What I'm missing?

[command works perfectly when I run `appcenter test run` from my local machine.]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How the things going? Does the open source could solve your puzzle? Don’t hesitate to let us know your any other puzzle about this issue.

Comment: I found the cause, additional options for run tests is different. For including specific categories we need to add options under prepare tests.

Comment: Do you want to add more options into the source code thus the task arguments can meet your demands? (In its source code file, this is the arguments definition: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AppCenterTestV1/appcentertest.ts#L84)

Comment: No. Prepare Tests arguments works as expected. My only concern is both of these areas (additional options from both Prepare & Run Tests ) builds the same test command on console but works on different way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people facing this issue, make sure you're providing your `--include-category AppCenterTest` under **Prepare Tests** area not under **Run tests**. Additional Options under Run Tests have different purpose it seems.

[image]

Comment: This fixed it for me, thanks

Answer (score 0):

> failed with exception "Unknown argument --include-category

In fact, the error message has been clear to express the caused reason. For this App Center Test task in Azure Devops, this command argument `--include-category` does not supportted.

Please Refer to the open source of about this task: [azure-pipelines-tasks/Tasks/AppCenterTestV1](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AppCenterTestV1/appcentertest.ts). You can check its logic and which arguments are supported by this task.

After you open the source file in github, go `function getTestRunner` and you will see that for test runner, the arguments it defined and supported to compile in this task does not include `--include-category`. That's why you receive the `Unknown argument` error.