# Filter tests in App center test task Azure pipeline

Tags: android, automated-tests, azure-pipelines, visual-studio-app-center

I have a some espresso tests in Android Studio in Kotlin. Some of the Test classes I have added them in a Test Suite class.
I have a azure pipeline set up with App center test task to run the tests in App center device.
How can I specify in the App center test task in Azure pipeline to run only that Test suite class?

Comment: In your test suite class, you could try to use annotations to specify which tests to run. Then in App center task use `--include-category AppCenterTest` to run. You can check [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58220125/14996050) for the details.